# How to make a search in Spring look for one word in the name and not for the full name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Wrote a search for a Spring site. The search searches for an article by its title, but it only searches for the exact title, and I need it to find it even if there is a word entered in the search in the title of the article. For example, if I have an article "Why is the earth round?", Now he will find this article if you enter "Why is the earth round?" In the search, but if you just enter the word "Why" he will not find anything. Please tell me how I can do what would be found by the word in the title.

My repository

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
 Iterable<Post> findByTitle(String title) throws Exception;
}
```

My service is written for this repository (by the way, tell me okay that I made it abstract in order to implement only findByTitle in it?)

```
@Service
public abstract class PostService implements PostRepository {

public PostRepository postRepository;

@Override
public Iterable<Post> findByTitle(String title) throws Exception {
    Iterable<Post> searchResult = postRepository.findByTitle(title);
    if(searchResult != null){
        throw new Exception("Пост не найден");
    }

    return searchResult;
}
}
```

My controller

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {

@Autowired
PostRepository postRepository;

@GetMapping("/search")
public String searchPage(){
    return "/search";
}

@PostMapping("search")
public String searchPage(@RequestParam("searchString") String searchString, Model model){
    if(searchString != null){
        try {
            Iterable<Post> searchResult = postRepository.findByTitle(searchString);
            model.addAttribute("searchResult", searchResult);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "search";
}
}
```

Comment: Rename your `findByTitle` to `findByTitleLikeIgnoreCase`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation . Regarding your service you aren't even using it, but it shouldn't `abstract` (you cannot use an instance of an `abstract` class) and your method is flawed as well (if there is a result throw an exception?).

Comment: You can write more about my abstract class, I don't quite understand what you mean ...

Comment: You aren't using it at all, so ditch it, next it is also flawed on multiple levels (the implementing interface, abstract, wrong result checking to name 3).

Comment: I understood everything, the abstract class did nothing, everything was done from the repository. Thanks.
I did as you advised(findByTitleLikeIgnoreCase), but the search continues to search as I was searching. I cannot find one word at a time ...

Comment: If you have a record with the value "aaabbbccc" and this record should be returned when searching for "bc" then you need to use containing which wraps your search string in '%%' which results in `like %bc%`. Further u can use IgnoreCase to - yes - ignore the case ;) So it goes like 
`postRepository.findByTitleContainingIgnoreCase(searchString);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a record with the value "aaabbbccc" and you want this record to be returned when searching for `bc` then you need to use **containing**.

`Containing` wraps your search string in `%%` which results to `like %bc%`.

Further u can use IgnoreCase to - yes - ignore the case ;)

So you need to use:

`postRepository.findByTitleContainingIgnoreCase(searchString);`

Edit:
For more details wrapping a search string in '%searchString%' means: *Ignore everything in front and after the search string so that the search string can be somewhere in the string.*

Comment: Thank you very much. I love this site, I learn more here than from all textbooks or tutorials. Thank you again, when I become a programmer of your level, I will also help people like me on this site =)